# Spring Boot - MongoDB aggregation nested documents returns empty result

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have a collection named results where each document has a token (unique) and a list of embedded documents *(services)*.

Sample:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("61e7eed15b9df6f80f0164c0"),
    token: '7683af2f-8f93-4387-9b6a-c89840d9525f',
    providers: [
      {
        _id: 2,
        companyName: 'Autopro'
      }
    ],
    services: [
      {
        _id: 1,
        serviceTypeId: 103
      },
      {
        _id: 5,
        serviceTypeId: 103
      },
      {
        _id: 6,
        serviceTypeId: 103,
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract using mongo template (spring boot) one service based on token and service id.
here is a code snippet:

```
UnwindOperation unwindServicesOp = Aggregation.unwind("services");
ProjectionOperation projectionOp = Aggregation.project(Fields.fields("services")).andExclude("_id");
HashSet<Criteria> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(Criteria.where("token").is(token));
set.add(Criteria.where("services._id").is(serviceId));
Criteria c = new Criteria();
c.andOperator(set);
MatchOperation matchOp = Aggregation.match(c);
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(Arrays.asList(unwindServicesOp, matchOp, projectionOp)),"results", Service.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
```

Service class:

```
public class Service implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7786799739639015883L;
    
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    private Integer serviceTypeId;
//setter and getters omitted for simplicity
}
```

Above code execute this query:

```
[{ "$unwind" : "$services"}, { "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "token" : "7683af2f-8f93-4387-9b6a-c89840d9525d"}, { "services._id" : 1}]}}, { "$project" : { "services" : 1, "_id" : 0}}]
```

getUniqueMappedResult() method returns empty Service object!

Is there any changes to do in my aggregation in order to get a Service object?

Comment: is token `7683af2f-8f93-4387-9b6a-c89840d9525d` in mongodb collection?  if removed `{ "token" : "7683af2f-8f93-4387-9b6a-c89840d9525d"}, ` from the mongodb query, it returns 1 result

Comment: Each result in results collection has a unique token. token is required in the filtering.

Comment: sorry my question not clear.  can you confirm please there is record with token "7683af2f-8f93-4387-9b6a-c89840d9525d" in database collection.

Because your sample data at the top has a different token value, I don't know if database has record with that token.

Comment: Yes sorry! I confirm there is already a document with this token in my collection.

Comment: sorry I don't see anything. I add your test data above, and change token value to `7683af2f-8f93-4387-9b6a-c89840d9525d`, and execute mongodb query you posted, and it returns 1 record of `{"services" : {"_id" : 1, "serviceTypeId" : 103 }}`

Comment: I found the solution. I Just added one more stage (last) to my aggregation: Aggregation.replaceRoot("services")

Answer (score 0):

There is one more stage (last one) to add in order to solve the issue:

```
ReplaceRootOperation replaceRootOp = Aggregation.replaceRoot("services");
```

Add it at last in the aggregation object.

I works.